# Symfony: command not found

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

I am trying working with symfony since past couple of months. Last night I did an auto remove to purge not needed repositories. After that I have not been able to create a new symfony project using the symfony command. When I run `Symfony new SecurityDemo 2.8.1` in the terminal,
I get the error

```
Symfony: command not found
```

I tried installing the **Symfony Installer** again as directed in the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html. I went to my root directory and followed the installation procedure as shown in the screenshot
[image]

Still I get the same error.

All help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am working with LAMP and am using PHP 5.6.

When I try to update the symfony Installer using `symfony self-update` I get the output

```
// Symfony Installer is already updated to the latest version (1.5.8).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure you installed the `symfony` command properly you have to call it with lowercase `s` and not `Symfony`.

The correct command is:

```
$ symfony new SecurityDemo 2.8.1
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#basing-your-project-on-a-specific-symfony-version

Answer (score 25):

Add the following line to your shell configuration file:

`export PATH="$HOME/.symfony/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: The shell configuration files are '~/.bashrc' and '~/.profile' in the home directory

Comment: To edit `~./bashrc` in Linux, you can use `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Don't forget to re 'source' your terminal session after adding to PATH or restart terminal window.  `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 15):

For me the fix was to reinstall symfony:

```
curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
```

see here https://symfony.com/download

as far as I experienced, it does not tamper with the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try call Symfony it in lowercase as example:

```
>symfony new SecurityDemo 2.8.1
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The right command would be:

```
php symfony new SecurityDemo 2.8.1
```

Not sure why it would not work without the word `php` even though the documentation does not prescribe it.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd your-project/
composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev
php bin/console server:start
```

Working beautifully for me on Fedora 33 Workstation

base: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/setup/built_in_web_server.html

Answer (score 1):

After Symfony CLI is installed successfully, you run the command below

```
sudo mv /home/{username}/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

to install it globally on your system

Replace `{username}` with your actual username.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I cannot use capital 'S' in symfony. using `symfony new project_name` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The Right Command is

```
symfony new SecurityDemo 2.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t use the Symfony installer for any reason, you can create Symfony applications with Composer, the dependency manager used by modern PHP applications.

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition SecurityDemo "2.8.1"
```

make sure you've already install composer.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash` to install Symfony CLI Installer. After installation run either of the next commands:

```
Use it as a local file:
  /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony

Or add the following line to your shell configuration file:
  export PATH="$HOME/.symfony5/bin:$PATH"

Or install it globally on your system:
  mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Then start a new shell and run 'symfony'

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
composer require symfony/flex
composer install
```

Comment: You don't need to install after require.